# In tabulator how to get a filter selected data

Tags: tabulator

In tabulator how to get a filter selected data using getSelectedData() function.I will try to pass a true value but does not working.
        Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible directly on tabulator but is easy to achieve.

If you use ***getSelectedData()*** to retrieve the selected data, the ***getData(true)*** to get the filtered data, you can then filter one from the other to get the filtered selected row data.

```
var filteredData= table.getData(true);
var selectedData = table.getSelectedData();

var filterSelectedData = filteredData.filter(value => -1 !== selectedData .indexOf(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get Oli's answer to work, but the code below worked for me, by using `findIndex` in the last line instead of `indexOf`:

```
var filteredData= table.getData('active');
var selectedData = table.getSelectedData();

var filterSelectedData = filteredData.filter(x => -1 !== selectedData.findIndex(y => y.id === x.id));
```

Comment: Sorry - I don't have enough rep points to comment on Oli's answer, so had to put my comment in a new answer.